# How to include Designer.cs into main class in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, designer, resx

When I create an empty project in Visual Studio there is a Form1.cs which contains the Subfiles Form1.designer.cs and Form1.resx.

When I download some sample code e.g. from CodeProject very often the Designer.cs isn´t there and the code of the designer is included in the Form1.cs. I tried to make it like this, but I just get an error of Visual Studio when I want to view the Form1.cs[Design] tab.

How can I achieve that the designer code is in the Form1.cs and not in a seperate file?

Addition:
Visual Studio creates my solution file in the project folder and the project files in the subfolders. In the sample codes often all files are in the same directory.

How may I achieve that?

Addition:
Here is a link to a sample Main.cs where the designer code is integrated to the
[Main.cs](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60191046/Main.cs)

Comment: Why do you *want* to do this? Why not just use it as it is?

Comment: Please don't. Most (if not all) the code in that file is generated by the designer. You will rarely have to edit it yourself.

Comment: It´s not because I want to use it like that, I only want to know how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cut and paste the code from Form1.Designer.cs to Form1.cs

Both Form1.Designer.cs and Form1.cs implements the class Form1. They use the keyword `partial` to split the declaration in two files. The reason is to separate the designer generated code from the code you write manually.

Comment: Ok, I found out, that the project file path is included in the solution file and can be changed with notepad++. @albin Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -2):

Add new class item and name it

```
<<Class Name>Class Name>.designer.cs
```

Comment: answer is rather short on both detail and explanation

Answer (score -3):

You can't Include Designer class as it is generated by Visual Studio when you include controls in your form.

If you have downloaded something which doesnt have designer.cs then that form must be unused one.

**Additional One.** It is directory structure VS Creates, so u can move the project file or solution file wherever u want to have.

Comment: No, they aren´t unused ones because they are the only ones and it´s the code running so it seems to work properly

Comment: Then they would have created controls programmatically. Like Button btnOK = new Button();

Comment: When I move the project files to the root project folder(where the solution file is) Visual Studio won´t load the project because it´s missing -.-

Comment: u have copy the entire folder structure to root foler.Not Just Project file as it used relative path.

Comment: i wrote "project file*s*" and I meant project file*s*